# Getting ref=yfp on urls

Tags: url, browser, google-analytics, seo

Since June 25th I've noticed some of my website urls on Google Analytics end with `ref=yfp`.

I tried google it, but only got other websites with the same problem.

Anybody knows what puts this on urls?
I'm guessing it is a browser extension. But which one?

Comment: Removed [tag:google-chrome-extension] since this question is not about extension _development_.

Comment: I'm voting for closing this question as off-topic. Non-programming SEO questions should be asked on the network site Pro Webmasters at http://webmasters.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I found it.

The [Brazilian Yahoo](https://br.yahoo.com/) started to show links to my website on its home page stories list. And these links end in `ref=yfp`.

The US Yahoo is different. It redirects to hsrd.yahoo.com and then to the original website.

Thank you guys for helping.

Answer (score 0):

I did some googling a while back and think it has something to do with yume

http://www.yume.com/sites/default/files/pdf/YFP_Pro.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Yahoo News automatically add that param into your urls.